# C++ Dynamic array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have problem with pointers.
My classes:

```
Zbior{
   Czasteczka* tablicaCzasteczek;  //it will be a pointer to dynamic array
   Zbior();
}
Czasteczka{
   Czasteczka();
   Czasteczka(int x, int y);
}
```

Constructor of Zbior:

```
Zbior::Zbior()
{
   this->tablicaCzasteczek = new Czasteczka[n];
   for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
   {
      this->tablicaCzasteczek[i] = NULL;   <-- here is 1st error
   }
   this->tablicaCzasteczek[0] = new Czasteczka(X, Y);   <-- 2nd error
   this->tablicaCzasteczek[1] = new Czasteczka(X, Y+1); <-- same error as above
}
```

Above code has to create dynamic array and add first and second object to this array.

Errors:

1.) Error 4 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

2.) Error 6 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Czasteczka *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Thank for all help! :)

Comment: `Czasteczka` is not a pointer. What is assigning null or the result of `new` to one supposed to do?

Comment: Can you assign `NULL` to an instance of `Czasteczka`??

Comment: It looks like you're familiar with Java. If so, there are many things you need to unlearn.

Comment: I'm assigning NULL to tablicaCzasteczek[i] to make sure, that all of pointer are empty

Comment: Unless you are doing this for "educational" purposes, save yourself a lot of trouble and use `std::vector<Czasteczka> tablicaCzasteczek;`.

Comment: _'...  that all of pointer are empty'_ There are no pointers! You already have `n` default constructed `Czasteczka`!

Comment: I think instead of declaring Czasteczka* tablicaCzasteczek you must declare as Czasteczka** tablicaCzasteczek

Comment: @goths Not that good idea, I'd prefer juanzo's proposal for getting it clearer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Czasteczka *tablicaCzasteczek` is a pointer to an instance of `Czasteczka`. It can also be holding a pointer to the first element of a decayed array of `Czasteczka`. This is the crucial part to understand:

`tablicaCzasteczek[0] = NULL;` is equivalent to `*tablicaCzasteczek = NULL`. That means you're trying to assign NULL to **an instance** of `Czasteczka`.

If you really want to make your code work, declare `tablicaCzasteczek` as

```
Czasteczka **tablicaCzasteczek;
```

and later on

```
this->tablicaCzasteczek = new Czasteczka*[n];
```

But that is calling for trouble if you don't know what you're doing (I don't see any destructors in your example).

As others have suggested, you'll be having much less headaches if you use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You'd be much better off with something like this:

```
class Czasteczka
{
public:
    Czasteczka(int x, int y);
    Czasteczka(const Czasteczka &other);
};

std::vector <Czasteczka> zbiorCzasteczek;
```

And then if you're on C++11:

```
zbiorCzasteczek.emplace_back(someX, someY);
```

Or if you're not:

```
zbiorCzasteczek.push_back(Czasteczka(someX, someY));
```

You can then access you're elements just as you would with an array (`zbiorCzasteczek[0]`). In this case, you won't have to worry about memory management, as `std::vector` will take care of that for you.

Of course you can put the vector as your class' member as well. I left out your `Zbior` class, as in your example it didn't do anything in particular.